# Why couldn't Harry Potter choose to be an international Quidditch player?

Tags: harry-potter

It doesn't make sense for Harry to be an Auror apart from the fact he wanted to

> kill Voldemort personally.

But we know from HBP that his passions lie in Quidditch(from Amortentia). So why wasn't his life's ambition to become a Quidditch player for England?
He was clearly better than Charlie, who is believed to be a flier of international caliber:

McGonagall, Book 1:

> “He caught that thing in his hand after a fifty-foot dive,” Professor McGonagall told Wood. “Didn’t even scratch himself. Charlie Weasley couldn’t have done it.”

Wood, Book 1:

> "That Quidditch cup'll have our name on it this year," said Wood happily as they trudged back up to the castle. "I wouldn't be surprised if you turn out better than Charlie Weasley, and he could have played for England if he hadn't gone off chasing dragons."

Comment: _He was clearly better than Charlie_.  Just curious, how did you infer that?

Comment: @Dawny33 Added in answer.

Comment: We don't know anything about how his ideas and ambitions changed after Voldemort's death.

Comment: Why couldn't he, or why *didn't* he? Why can't most local high school sports stars become international professional players?

Comment: "It doesn't make sense for Harry to be an Auror". Citation needed for this statement. DA is the subject Harry is shown to enjoy most, and he is repeatedly mentioned to be the best in his year at it, even more so than Hermione.

Comment: “It is our choices...that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.”

Comment: I don't think though, that after the events of Book 7, he couldn't have gone for Quidditch. He was reasonably talented in DADA, and he had an edge in it for the DA meetings after Book 3. It's even said in the first task(GoF) that "he was back where he belonged".

Comment: @cst1992 wasnt the quote from GoF, "he was back where he belonged" when he got on his broom?

Comment: @Himarm Yup. That's what I'm referring to. It was his passion.

Comment: Just because it was his passion doesn't mean he would want it to be his job... maybe that would even be a reason *not* to do it professonally: he likes it, but as a job it's probably only 10% fun and talent, and 90% hard work and constant training in all weather...  I'd choose a nice cubicle in the MoM over that too.... and he probably wouldn't want to run into his wife during a professional game, either.... also: even in school he did not even manage one whole "season" where he finished every single game (with just **3** played in a school year)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't really mater the skill Harry possessed, or the passion he had for it. What maters is that when confronted with choices for a job in year 5, instead of deciding to work towards being a quidditch star, he opted for a job as an Auror. This shows that no mater his passion for the sport, at the end of the day he never truly wanted it to be a career, it was simply a fun past time he enjoyed.

> “Well, it’d be cool to be an Auror,” said Ron in an offhand voice.
>
> “Yeah, it would,” said Harry fervently.
>
> “But they’re, like, the elite,” said Ron. “You’ve got to be really
>   good.  What about you, Hermione?”
>
> “I don’t know,” said Hermione. “I think I’d really like to do some-
>   thing worthwhile.”
>
> “An Auror’s worthwhile!” said Harry.

**Fervent**

> 1. having or showing great warmth or **intensity of spirit**, feeling, enthusiasm, etc.; ardent:
>      a fervent admirer; a fervent plea.
> 2. hot; burning; glowing.

By his conversation with Ron and Hermione it shows that he does have passion to become an Auror.